# Organize Code for GUI and ActionListener in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I am new to Java and was wondering how I would go about implementing `ActionListener` code in my project. I am aware of inner classes and the implementation the `ActionListener` interface, but going down that road makes the code look more messy than it probably should.

Would I write another class `ActionCode` that implements `ActionListener` and extends GUI or what road would you suggest and why?

What's your best practice advise on that and where can I find those guidelines?
(The JavaDoc seems to explain the basic implementation of `ActionListener`s, but doesn't seem to have any model how to organize large/medium projects).

Comment: Use an Adapter the provides a default implementation for the methods. Then, provide overrides where different behavior is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement an interface and override methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5647800/608639)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, there is no "best" approach. Even the code examples from sun/oracle tutorials use  different ways to implement listeners.

From my experience, a good approach is:

- Use anonymous implementations: People know this pattern and will quickly recognize it. It helps the reader to understand the code if there is a common way to do things
- Have a special method, which only handles the listeners (e.g. `private void addListeners()`): Again, this helps everyone to recognize it and to know where to search for all the logic
- Keep the listeners simple. This means less than 5-10 lines of code. If you need more complex logic, call a method.
- Keep the number of listeners small. If you need > 50 listeners, you should probably refactor your view. If you need more than 10, you could think about refactoring.

Beside this general points, there are always exceptions. Like if you have a lot of Components with the same behavior, you could write a generic listener with a switch/case. (Typical example: buttons from a calculator or menu buttons).
Or if you have the same logic for multiple components, you could use a specific class.
And so on.

And just to mention it, because there are some examples in the sun/oracle tutorials: Try to avoid implementing a listener interface with the view class itself. This could be ok if you have only one listener, but it is most of the times awful for multiple events from multiple source with different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Code style can be a matter of personal taste, but modern literature suggests it's more than that. Let the chapter on Classes in [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) show you the way.

> Classes Should Be Small!
>
> The ﬁrst rule of classes is that they should be small. The second rule
>   of classes is that they should be smaller than that. No, we’re not
>   going to repeat the exact same text from the Functions chapter. But as
>   with functions, smaller is the primary rule when it comes to designing
>   classes. As with functions, our immediate question is always “How
>   small?” With functions we measured size by counting physical lines.
>   With classes we use a different measure. We count responsibilities...
>
> **The Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) states that a class or
>   module should have one, and only one, reason to change.** This principle
>   gives us both a deﬁnition of responsibility, and a guidelines for
>   class size. Classes should have one responsibility—one reason to
>   change...
>
> The problem is that too many of us think that we are done once the
>   program works. We fail to switch to the other concern of organization
>   and cleanliness. We move on to the next problem rather than going back
>   and breaking the overstuffed classes into decoupled units with single
>   responsibilities. At the same time, *many developers fear that a large
>   number of small, single-purpose classes makes it more difﬁcult to
>   understand the bigger picture. They are concerned that they must
>   navigate from class to class in order to ﬁgure out how a larger piece
>   of work gets accomplished. However, a system with many small classes
>   has no more moving parts than a system with a few large classes.* There
>   is just as much to learn in the system with a few large classes. So
>   the question is: Do you want your tools organized into toolboxes with
>   many small drawers each containing well-deﬁned and well-labeled
>   components? Or do you want a few drawers that you just toss everything
>   into?
>
> **Every sizable system will contain a large amount of logic and
>   complexity. The primary goal in managing such complexity is to
>   organize it so that a developer knows where to look to ﬁnd things and
>   need only understand the directly affected complexity at any given
>   time.** In contrast, a system with larger, multipurpose classes always
>   hampers us by insisting we wade through lots of things we don’t need
>   to know right now. To restate the former points for emphasis: We want
>   our systems to be composed of many small classes, not a few large
>   ones. Each small class encapsulates a single responsibility, has a
>   single reason to change, and collaborates with a few others to achieve
>   the desired system behaviors.

So, based on these heuristics, Nested Classes break SRP. They should almost never happen. Instead, have your GUI classes include instance members of the ActionListeners they register. Keep the listeners in a separate *.listener package. Use interfaces to make them replaceable (Strategy Pattern) wherever deemed effective.

Answer (score 0):

Java and Swing encourage lots of little objects like Listeners and Actions. It's a lot of boiler-plate, but that's the way Java is. There's little benefit in fighting it.

Creating anonymous listeners inline is fairly painless:

```
JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ok();
    }
});
```

But, you often need to reuse actions, say to assign the same action to a menu and a button. You might put them in your main application window as inner classes:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;


public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    ZapAction zapAction;

    public MainWindow() {

        setSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        zapAction = new ZapAction();

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Foo");
        menu.add(new JMenuItem(zapAction));
        menuBar.add(menu);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JButton zapButton = new JButton(zapAction);

        add(zapButton);
    }

    public void zap() {
        // do some zapping
        System.out.println("Zap!");
        // maybe we're all done zapping?
        zapAction.setEnabled(isZappingPossible());
    }

    public boolean isZappingPossible() {
        // determine if there's zapping to be done
        return Math.random() < 0.9;
    }

    class ZapAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ZapAction() {
            super("Zap");
            putValue(AbstractAction.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Zap something");
            putValue(AbstractAction.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                KeyEvent.VK_Z, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
            putValue(AbstractAction.SMALL_ICON, 
                new ImageIcon(MainWindow.class.getResource("/icons/zap.png")));
            setEnabled(true);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            zap();
        }
    }
}

public class Zap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here, `ZapAction` is package-private visibility. I put all the UI code in it's own package (say `org.myorg.myproject.ui`). So, all the UI objects have access to the actions.

In a complex swing app, I've gone as far as to create a UI facade layer, which makes a nice place for the actions and all the code that wires them up to various controls. It also makes a convenient place for external code to interact with the UI, keeping UI code isolated from core application code.